# how to upload the excel file to sharepoint office365

Tags: development

I have to upload the files[excel] to share point server(online) office 365, using .net c# code only

i have only the destination url and excel files.
note:I dont have the sharepoint installation.

Regards,
veera prasad.

Comment: This is a little vague.  Why do you have to use .NET to upload to a 365 instance?  I assume you have some sort of access restriction?  I'm reasonably confident that these restrictions will not be lifted by simply coding your way around it.  You'll still need access credentials or impersonation details.

Answer (score 1):

You can use C# CSOM for this.You can use [File.SaveBinaryDirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.file.savebinarydirect%28v=office.14%29) Method to upload document using Client object model.

```
using (var clientContext = new ClientContext("https://yoursiteurl.com"))
      {
           string passWd = "password";
           SecureString securePassWd = new SecureString();
           foreach (var c in passWd.ToCharArray())
            {
                securePassWd.AppendChar(c);
            }
            clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("username", securePassWd);

           using (var fs = new FileStream("fileName", FileMode.Open))
           {
               var fi = new FileInfo("fileName");
               var list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Doc Library");
               clientContext.Load(list.RootFolder);
               clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
               var fileUrl = String.Format("{0}/{1}", list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl, fi.Name);
               Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(clientContext, fileUrl, fs, true);
            }
       }
```

Note: Make sure that the user credentials used in the code has contribute access to the library.

Comment: how about sites with 2FA?